# Determine Java version through JMX

Tags: java, jmx

I'm looking to **remotely** determine the version of Java that a particular process is running on through JMX.  Specifically, I would like something like "1.6.0_26", which is what `System.getProperty("java.version")` would return.

Through the RunTime MBean, I can check the VmName and VmVersion attributes, which give "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM" and "20.1-b02", respectively.  I'm not sure where the "20.1-b02" comes from; is there a way to match that to the "1.6.0_26" version?

Comment: @hd1 espousing? What? In any case, I'm looking to use JMX, not JDWP.

Comment: VmVersion is rather well documented on the link I posted, @TylerHobbs

Comment: Perhaps the behavior changed in Java 7? In Java 6, as I pointed out in my question, it does not match the "java.version" system property.

Comment: @TylerHobbs what does`javax.management.MBeanServerDelegate.getImpmlementationVersion` give you?

Comment: @Kent ah, that actually works. I had to query "JMImplementation:type=MBeanServerDelegate". Interesting approach, thanks!

Comment: I think @MarcelStör 's getSystemProperties() is better and safe. Since I tried here, the getImp..Version() has b18 in the endm, but the java version without it. ("1.7.0_10" and "1.7.0_10-b18")

Comment: @Kent, same here `MBeanServerDelegate.ImplementationVersion` returns the version _including_ the build number (-bxx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of hints for the `java.lang.Runtime` bean:

- SpecVersion
- LibraryPath/BootClassPath (most likely in the folder name)
- SystemProperties -> `java.runtime.version`

**Edit**

As @Kent pointed out `java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean.getSystemProperties()` in code is the same as `SystemProperties` -> `java.runtime.version` in a JMX client like JConsole.

Comment: SpecVersion unfortunately just reads "1.0".  I considered LibraryPath/BootClassPath, but as you say, that depends the path for the installation dir having very specific naming requirements.  I'm not aware of a way to check any given SystemProperty through JMX, but that would be awesome.

Comment: -1 SpecVersion is not what he is looking 4. e.g. mine specVersion is 1.7 but jre version is "1.7.0_10";  we cannot/shouldn't count on the directory name at all. my JAVA_HOME is /opt/java, LibraryPath basically is pointing to /usr/lib, no version number at all. And OP is looking for a path via JMX.Not by SystemProperties.

Comment: @Kent, that's why I said "hints", ok? And `SystemProperties` doesn't refer to system properties but to the JMX `SystemProperties` attribute of the `java.lang.Runtime` bean. It allows you to navigate through all the system properties. Don't think your down vote is appropriate.

Comment: @MarcelStör sorry, I thought "hints" should sit in comments instead of answers.

Comment: @MarcelStör sorry again, I thought the SystemProperties meant System.getProperty().  java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean.getSystemProperties()  should work. can you somehow edit your answer (whatever), I cannot upvote..it is locked...

Comment: @MarcelStör I didn't even notice the SystemProperties attribute because JConsole can't show the values.  That's perfect, and actually helps me out with a few other things. Thanks!

Comment: @TylerHobbs, yeah everything in bold is double-clickable for details.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that older versions of the JVM / JMX return the wrong thing for specVersion, so using the technique that @Kent provided works much better:

```
        getLogger().finest("Checking JVM version");
    String specVersion = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getSpecVersion();
    getLogger().log(Level.FINEST, "Specification Version from JMX = ''{0}''", specVersion);

    // Because of bug in the above call, earlier versions of JMX reported the version of
    // JMX and not Java (so 1.6 reports 1.0 - replacing with the call below fixes this problem
    // and consistently returns the specification of the JVM that is being used.
    String javaVersion = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getSystemProperties().get("java.specification.version");
    getLogger().log(Level.FINEST, "java.specification.version found ''{0}''", javaVersion);
```